# Проблема с настройкой vim. Слетело отображение файлов

Tags: vim, vimrc

Раньше при использовании команды :e высвечивались файлы и папки в директории. После установки парочки пакетов все слетело. Пробовал очистить .vimrc файл, не помогло.
До(фото не мое, но вот как выглядело):
[image: до]

После:
[image: после]

Прошу помочь с проблемой.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вам нужно настроить `set wildmode`. Что-то вроде `set wildmode=longest,list`. Больше информации в `:h cmdline.txt`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо огромное, поставил wildmenu, все заработало.

Comment: Запишите ваши исправления как ответ. Всем польза будет.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто прописать set wildmenu в .vimrc